# AJAX POST returning null values

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have tried and tested various methods for completing this task for about a day now. Please be forewarned that I am building this simply, and then working my way up!

I have a form that consists of a textarea, and two input fields. The input fields allow a `XMLHttpRequest` to send information pertaining to a username, and message - sent to a chatroom that I am trying to make.

The problem that I have with my request, is simply that I can send the information, and insert a row into a database, but I can't get any information back! You will see from the code below, that I have put an alert in, to check what the response text is, but it comes back as null (not `undefined`, but `""`). Please check the code below:

```
function insertMessage() {
    var username = document.getElementById('username').value;
    var message = document.getElementById('message').value;
    var queryString = "username=" + username + "&message=" + message;

    // send the username and message information to be inserted into the database
    var url = 'classes/chatroom/chatroom.upload.php';

    // create xml request
    var request = createCORSRequest("POST", url)

    // create a function that will receive data sent from the server
    request.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
            alert(request.responseText);
        }
    }

    request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    request.send(queryString);
}

function createRequest(method, url) {
    var thisRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

    if ("withCredentials" in thisRequest) {
        // thisRequest has 'withCredentials' property only if it supports CORS
        thisRequest.open(method, url, true);
    } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") { // if IE use XDR
        thisRequest = new XDomainRequest();
        thisRequest.open(method, url);
    } else {
        thisRequest = null;
    }
    return thisRequest;
}
```

The code that pertains to the insertion of a database row is:

```
<?php
include 'chatroom.config.inc.php';  // the database file

$message_username = $_POST['username'];
$message_content = $_POST['message'];

if ($message_username == "Username: Once entered, you don't have to enter again" || $message_username == "") {
    $message_username = "Guest";
}

if ($message_content == "Message:" || $message_content == "") {}
else {
    $users->post_message($message_username, $message_content); // insert database row using PDO query
}
?>
```

Could anyone provide a clue as to where I'm going wrong?

Comment: You should look into [`jQuery`](http://www.jquery.com). That would allow you to run simple [`GET`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) / [`POST`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) requests.

Comment: Sure. You are not outputting anything from your insertion script. It's just inserting a row. What do you want to do from there?

Comment: Also use Firebug or some development tools to see the request in action (in the console) so that you can know exactly the http response. The alert should fire, even though you don't have any output text. jQuery ajax would be much simipler and less prone to errors, IMHO as well.

Comment: I want to retrieve the data i have sent, and then use that information to update a textarea - that is currently on the form that evokes the insertMessage() function.

Comment: Okay Chas, thankyou! I will download Firebug and check out the information right away! I have honestly tried using jQuery, and that didn't even work correctly, for me. I had a web developer friend look at it too, and even he couldn't figure out why it wasn't working. I am using a wamp server, would locally running files prove to be problematic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code looks good to me, your PHP code is inserting the data in DB but it isn't returning back any text or value.

For values to be retrieved on the client side i.e. on successful completion of your ajax request, you will have to send the data to client side.

Try using php's echo function and return the text / value.

Comment: Okay, that actually worked! Haha! I can't believe it was something so simple! Thank you so much :) I simply added an echo to the end of my upload.php file, and it returned the value i wanted! :)